# Git- How to kill ssh-agent properly on Linux

Tags: linux, git, ssh, ssh-agent

I am using git on linux, when pushing to gitlab, sometimes it either stuck at:

> debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [52.167.219.168] port 22.

or

> debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
>
> debug3: send packet: type 100

Seems restarting linux could solve it, but no body like to reboot machines.
So, I am trying to kill ssh-agent process, then restart it.

But the process is always `defunct` after kill, and then I can't use git via ssh at all, so is there any way to restart the ssh-agent, or solve the issue described above without restarting the machine?

---

**@Update**

The ssh keys that I use include key phrase, which I would input on first use of a ssh key.

The issue usually occurs after I bring the Linux desktop back from sleep, thus the network is reconnected, not sure whether this matters?

Again, does any one knows how to kill or restart a `ssh-agent` agent, without making it become `defunct`?

Comment: How is this related to `ssh-agent`?

Comment: @Jakuje Because it's git via ssh, and the ssh-agent help to handle username & password via ssh keys automatically.

Comment: `ssh-agent` does not handle any passwords. Only a private keys and operations with them. But if `ssh` is hanging on `connecting to ...` it is certainly not related to the `ssh-agent`, but to some network issues, where restarting `ssh-agent` will not help you.

Comment: @Jakuje I mean it help to avoid username & password with ssh keys, without it you need username & password. And I believe it's related to `ssh-agent` in some way, because on windows, restarting `ssh-agent` would fix similar issue, it's just I can't restart it on linux, instead the reboot would fix it.

Answer (score 28):

You can kill ssh-agent by running:

```
ssh-agent -k
```

**!NB**, `-k` argument works only if $SSH_AGENT_PID environment variable is set. `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` sets the variable, but there're also other methods to start the agent without setting the environment variable. E.g., connecting to a remote server implicitly starts the agent without setting the variable. In this case, you need to use `pidof ssh-agent` or `pgrep ssh-agent` to find the ssh-agent PID and then kill it.

Comment: Doesn't work: SSH_AGENT_PID not set, cannot kill agent

Comment: Then, most likely, the ssh-agent is not running. Try to start the agent running `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` and then kill it. What OS and shell you're using, by the way?

Comment: No the agent is definitely running. You assume it is only started by doing `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`, but that's not the only way it can be started. It is also started when you try to ssh to a remote server. In that case, `SSH_AGENT_PID` is not set in the current shell, but running `pidof ssh-agent` or `pgrep ssh-agent` shows you the PID of the one that is running.

Comment: @EduardMukans Please add also that the `-k` only works if the environment variable `SSH_AGENT_PID` is set properly, that's what `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` actually does. BTW: that was already discussed in comments a long time ago. So please consider adding this valuable information with another update. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Many ways:

- `killall ssh-agent`
- `SSH_AGENT_PID="$(pidof ssh-agent)" ssh-agent -k`
- `kill -9 $(pidof ssh-agent)`

*`pidof` is from the [procps](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps) project. You may be able to find it for your distro if it is packaged*

Comment: killall did not do anything in my case. kill -9 $(pidof ...) worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this bash script to terminate the SSH agent:

```
#!/bin/bash

## in .bash_profile

SSHAGENT=`which ssh-agent`
SSHAGENTARGS="-s"
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" -a -x "$SSHAGENT" ]; then
    eval `$SSHAGENT $SSHAGENTARGS`
    trap "kill $SSH_AGENT_PID" 0
fi

## in .logout

if [ ${SSH_AGENT_PID+1} == 1 ]; then
    ssh-add -D
    ssh-agent -k > /dev/null 2>&1
    unset SSH_AGENT_PID
    unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK
fi
```

Comment: I just tried this on my linux, the ssh-agent process become defunct after using the script, same result as `kill -9` command.

Answer (score 4):

yes, ssh-agent might be defunct: `[ssh-agent] <defunct>`

trying to kill the agent could help:

`eval "$(ssh-agent -k)"`

but also try to check your keyring process (e.g. gnome-keyring-daemon), restart it or even remove the ssh socket file:

`rm /run/user/$UID/keyring/ssh`

Answer (score 0):

It shows `defunct` probably because its parent process is still monitoring it, so it's not removed from the process table. It's not a big deal, the process is killed. Just start a new ssh-agent:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)

ssh-add
```