# Stop ssh-agent from ever persisting password

Tags: ssh

As in the title. I WANT to type in my password every time I do a git push or pull. Currently, it prompts me to enter in the passphrase every restart and then caches it, but I don't want that.

I'm not sure what I did to cause this as it never happened before on any of my other machines across the years

Answer (score 0):

With SSH, only a passphrase (if you have created a private SSH key protected with a passphrase) would be asked, then cached by the ssh-agent.

Typing a password would mean using an HTTPS URL (one requiring your remote GitHub or GitLab user account name, and password or token).

Comment: Sure, but I don't want it to be cached by the ssh-agent. How would I make it stop?

Comment: @IanQuah By killing the ssh-agent process. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67991080/6309)