# How would I delete all current ssh keys?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, ssh, ssh-keys

I have tried some things already after reading some forums, but this still shows up when I list all of my ssh keys.

[image: Picture of what I have tried]

How would I delete them all to start fresh in learning them?
I apologize if this is a stupid question or a simple fix, I am just learning how to use Git and all of its technologies.

Comment: Your last command does seem to have deleted the keys? Are you just worried about the `.config.swp` file?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: yes, sorry I'm so new to this. what does that file mean?

Comment: Deleting your config file as well might not have been what you wanted. You have backups, I hope.

Comment: It doesn't look like `~` and `/home/vivek` are the same directory, either.

Comment: No need to change your question. It is a legitimate one, and I have answered it below. Next time, consider https://superuser.com/ for this type of question.

Comment: Thank you "VonC" for legitimately being a decent human being and pointing me in the right direction instead just showing me rules and regs saying how I'm in the wrong space for this type of question.

Comment: @Lan you are most welcome. Sorry for this Stack Overflow first experience. Have a look around, it is a good community.

Answer (score 1):

When you `ls ~/.ssh`, there is no more keys (public or private)

The `.config.swp` is just a [swap file created by `vi`](https://fileinfo.com/extension/swp) and can be ignored.

You might also need to [kill the `ssh-agent`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66630518/6309), if you previously added private encrypted keys (which were passphrase-protected).

---

`~` should expand to `${HOME}`, which, as commented, might not be `/home/vivek`.
Make sure to know which user account you are currently logged in:

```
id -a
```